# Can't run ps script from code. Issue with ExecutionPolicy

Tags: azure, powershell

I have WebApp and Webjob in Azure. My webjob tries to run some powershell scripts using `PowerShell.Create()` then `ps.AddScript(script)` and `ps.Invoke()`.
In my local environment webjob works well and all ps scripts are executed correctly. But in Azure webjobs throws following fail:

> One or more errors occurred. (File D:\local\Temp...\Login.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts are disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies.

After that I try to set execution policy as urestricted but this command doesn't work in azure console.

My current execution policy:

```
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine    RemoteSigned
```

I have tried the following ways to change execution policy(I run all commands in azure portal console):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

Set-ExecutionPolicy : Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\M
icrosoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell' is denied. To change the 
execution policy for the default (LocalMachine) scope, start Windows 
PowerShell with the "Run as administrator" option.
```

But I don't know how to run the console in Azure as Administrator.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser

Set-Executionpolicy : The specified registry key does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-Executionpolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted
```

How to change ExecutionPolicy in Azure? Or how to avoid issue with disabling ps scripts?
Please, help me!)

Comment: can you try and launch powershell with `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Shell (I think you mean this with Azure Portal Console) has nothing to do with your Azure App Service. Have you tried [setting the policy in C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34140309/set-execution-policy-from-process) instead?